# UPDATE: Site design updates are now live!

Tags: discussion, design

A majority of the changes are not visible; these tweaks go along with recent updates that were made to Stack Overflow:

- We have moved the site's CSS to a newly refactored LESS system, so that it's easier for us to fix SE network CSS bugs globally and launch new features in the future.
- We are updating the graphics to SVG for retina support.
- We've fixed a LOT of obscure bugs that arose when new features were not thoroughly tested across the entire network.
- We have launched the shiny new user profile!
  Visually it should "feel" the same as the old site with slight layout adjustments.

This update should retro-actively fix most of the old design bugs, but if you see any new bugs, or old ones not yet fixed, please post an answer here to let us know!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's just me, but the header looks weird IMHO because the blue top bar doesn't align with `div#header` (using Firefox 38 on Linux). Didn't you forget to add `body { background-position: 0 34px; }` ?

Comment: Ah, that's better. Thanks for fixing it. You're welcome!

Comment: No problem. Good catch.